# Как сделать конвертацию валюты через умножение?

Tags: математика

Как одной формулой конвертировать валюту?

Например

119.59917 TJS, нужно получить рубли по курсу TJSRUB = 10.8169

190.00000 RUB, нужно получить доллар по курсу RUBUSD = 68

Comment: А причем тут javascript? Думаю, что это чистая математика.

Comment: @Visman: поправил

Comment: А что вы минусуете? Ответа то не знаете...

Comment: знаем, просто вопрос был сформулирован некорректно.

Comment: Теперь корректно, снял минус.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Деление - это операция обратная умножению, так что её всегда можно заменить на операцию умножения на обратное число, т.е.:

```
a / b = a * (1 / b)
```

Так что можешь просто хранить курсы в нормализованном виде и использовать умножение всегда.

Comment: Не понимаю. 
Вот мне нужно из рублей получить доллары. 190*68 = 12 973.51.
а мне нужно получить 2.78
Каким образом это сделать?
Мне нужен один универсальный метод, который дал правильный результат

Comment: 190 * (1 / 68) = 2,79, то есть курс не 68, а 0,014705882 - так его и хранить, и применять

Comment: Курсы я получаю от финансистов в таком виде  68р=1доллар. Получается, нужно слелать предварительную операцию ?

Comment: Ну да, один раз, при получении прогоняешь через такой конвертер, записываешь в БД, а потом уже нормально умножаешь

Comment: Не лучше ли в таком случае сделать проверку во время конвертации? Как по вашему потом пользователи будут обновлять курсы валют?

Comment: Наконец-то. Я вас понял. Большое спасибо за ответ. И всем кто участвовал в также. Вопрос решен